# "qmake" and "make" QtRemoteObjects (from git) for Qt 5.7 Android on Windows 7 does not work

Tags: android, qt, makefile, qmake

I have cloned the QtRemoteObjects repository from: http://code.qt.io/cgit/playground/qtremoteobjects.git/
on my Windows 7 using GitBash.exe.
The project files are download to "D:\Daten\Android\qtremoteobjects\". Based on the article on this website: https://www.kdab.com/qt-android-create-android-service-using-qt/ I run this command in GitBash:

```
$ cd d:/Daten/Android/qtremoteobjects/
$ git c:/Qt5.7.0/5.7/android_armv7/bin/qmake -r && make && make install
```

### QMAKE PART

For the qmake part these errors show up:

```
Reading D:/Daten/Android/qtremoteobjects/tests/auto/cmake/cmake.pro 
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
```

meaning the system could not find the given path. And the next two errors are:

```
WARNING: Failure to find: rep_server_source.h
Project MESSAGE: cmake executable not found. Not running CMake unit tests
```

**First question:** Why doesnt the system find the **path for cmake.pro** and **rep_server_source.h** and why isnt the cmake executable not found even though I have separately installed CMake.

### MAKE PART

The next error that shows up is:

```
bash: make: command not found
```

As a solution to this I separated the qmake and make process. I first just ran qmake

```
$ git c:/Qt5.7.0/5.7/android_armv7/bin/qmake -r
```

and when qmake is finished (and the same errors as above still show up) i run mingw32-make.exe from Qt5.7->Tools in the qtremoteobjects folder:

```
$ c:/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make.exe
```

and this is the result:

```
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || C:/Qt5.7.0/5.7/android_x86/bin/qmake.exe
D:/Daten/Android/qtremoteobjects/src/src.pro -o Makefile ) && C:/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/Daten/Android/qtremoteobjects/src'
cd remoteobjects/ && ( test -e Makefile || C:/Qt5.7.0/5.7/android_x86/bin/qmake.exe D:/Daten/Android/qtremoteobjects/src/remoteobjects/remoteobjects.pro -o Makefile ) && C:/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'D:/Daten/Android/qtremoteobjects/src/remoteobjects'
D:\Daten\Android\android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows/bin/i686-linux-android-g++ -c -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -std=c++11 -mfpmath=sse -O2 -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -Wvla -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_XKBCOMMON -DQT_BUILD_REMOTEOBJECTS_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x050000 -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_BYTEARRAY -DQT_NO_URL_CAST_FROM_STRING -DQT_BUILD_REMOTEOBJECTS_LIB -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -Ic:/utils/openssl-android-master/include -I../../include -I../../include/QtRemoteObjects -I../../include/QtRemoteObjects/5.6.1 -I../../include/QtRemoteObjects/5.6.1/QtRemoteObjects -I. -IC:/Qt5.7.0/5.7/android_x86/include -IC:/Qt5.7.0/5.7/android_x86/include/QtNetwork -IC:/Qt5.7.0/5.7/android_x86/include/QtCore/5.7.0 -IC:/Qt5.7.0/5.7/android_x86/include/QtCore/5.7.0/QtCore -IC:/Qt5.7.0/5.7/android_x86/include/QtCore -I.moc -isystem D:/Daten/Android/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem D:/Daten/Android/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/include -isystem D:/Daten/Android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-x86/usr/include -IC:/Qt5.7.0/5.7/android_x86/mkspecs/android-g++ -o .obj/qconnection_local_backend.obj qconnection_local_backend.cpp
Makefile:1720: recipe for target '.obj/qconnection_local_backend.obj' failed
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, D:\Daten\Android\android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows/bin/i686-linux-android-g++ -c -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300 -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -std=c++11 -mfpmath=sse -O2 -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-exceptions -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -Wvla -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_XKBCOMMON -DQT_BUILD_REMOTEOBJECTS_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x050000 -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_BYTEARRAY -DQT_NO_URL_CAST_FROM_STRING -DQT_BUILD_REMOTEOBJECTS_LIB -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -Ic:/utils/openssl-android-master/include -I../../include -I../../include/QtRemoteObjects -I../../include/QtRemoteObjects/5.6.1 -I../../include/QtRemoteObjects/5.6.1/QtRemoteObjects -I. -IC:/Qt5.7.0/5.7/android_x86/include -IC:/Qt5.7.0/5.7/android_x86/include/QtNetwork -IC:/Qt5.7.0/5.7/android_x86/include/QtCore/5.7.0 -IC:/Qt5.7.0/5.7/android_x86/include/QtCore/5.7.0/QtCore -IC:/Qt5.7.0/5.7/android_x86/include/QtCore -I.moc -isystem D:/Daten/Android/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -isystem D:/Daten/Android/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/include -isystem D:/Daten/Android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-x86/usr/include -IC:/Qt5.7.0/5.7/android_x86/mkspecs/android-g++ -o .obj/qconnection_local_backend.obj qconnection_local_backend.cpp, ...) failed.
make (e=2): Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
mingw32-make[2]: *** [.obj/qconnection_local_backend.obj] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/Daten/Android/qtremoteobjects/src/remoteobjects'
Makefile:44: recipe for target 'sub-remoteobjects-make_first-ordered' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-remoteobjects-make_first-ordered] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/Daten/Android/qtremoteobjects/src'
Makefile:46: recipe for target 'sub-src-make_first' failed
mingw32-make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
```

**Second Question** Why is make not successful here? what do these errors mean? What is wrong with  **'.obj/qconnection_local_backend.obj'**

Is it because I am running make on Windows?

Thanks,